# Clear the interval in d3.js

Tags: d3.js

I'm using d3.interval instead of the javascript setInterval. The problem is that I don't know how to stop it, since I was using ClearInterval and it clearly doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use method `stop` for this. This method works for both [`d3.timer`](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer#interval) and [`d3.interval`](https://github.com/d3/d3-timer#interval);

```js
var interval = d3.interval(function(elapsed) {
  if (elapsed > 2600) {
    interval.stop(); // <== !!!
    return;
  }
  
  console.log(elapsed);
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.11.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```